# Buscar números primos en un array y guardarlos en otro

Tags: javascript

a ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Tengo un problema que me pide generar un array con 50 numeros aleatorios, indicar cuales de ellos son primos y guardarlos en otro array.Este vendría a ser el código que he podido sacar pero algo falla:

```
var array1=[];
var array2=[];
var longArray1=50;
var divisor=2;
var primo=true;
var contador1,i,numero;

for (contador1=0;contador1<=longArray1;contador1++) {
    array1[contador1] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 5;
}

for (i=0;i<=longArray1;i++) {
    numero=array1[i];
    while (divisor<numero) {
        if (numero % divisor==0) {
            primo=false;
        }
        divisor++;
    }
    if (primo==true) {
        array2.push(numero);
    }
}
document.querySelector(".demo0").innerHTML = array1;
document.querySelector(".demo1").innerHTML = array2;
```

Comment: No pongas imágenes, pon el código es más fácil poder ayudarte de esa forma

Comment: Tienes razón. Acabo de editar, borrando la imagen y he añadido el código.

Comment: Tu ciclo for solo itera sobre el arreglo array1 pero en ninguna momento verifica si el numero es primo o no.
Para darte una idea, te diré que los números primos son aquellos que solo son divisibles por si mismos y por la unidad. En otras palabras los números primos solo tienen 2 divisiones exactas. A modo de ejemplo podrías buscar cuantas divisiones exactas tiene cada numero de tu arreglo y aquellas que solo tengan 2 serán los números primos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo te hace falta reiniciar ciertos valores al principio de cada iteración, `primo` y `divisor`, divisor al principio vale 2 para el primer número y aumenta de uno en uno, así que para el siguiente número su valor debe regresar a 2, de igual forma con tu bandera "primo", en tu ciclo while puede cambiar a false así que hay que reiniciarlo para cada número que se verifique:

```
for (i=0;i<=longArray1;i++) {
    primo = true;
    divisor = 2;
    numero=array1[i];
    while (divisor<numero) {    
        if (numero % divisor==0) {
            primo=false;
            break;
        }
        divisor++;
    }
    if (primo) {
        array2.push(numero);
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Ese era el fallo. Muchas gracias Luis por su ayuda.